# How to initialize JAXB with SAX properly?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax

I have a class where multiple threads access it (Something similar to a servlet). There is a method named onEvent which takes an `InputStream` and unmarshals the input stream received.

To unmarshal, I initialized JAXB and XMLReader in the constructor like below

```
try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductInventory.class);
            jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            final SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            reader = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.error("Exception while initializing JAXB", e);
        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            logger.error("Exception while initializing sax xml reader", e);
        }
```

In the onEvent method I wrote the below code

```
final InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);
final SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(reader, inputSource);
SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(saxSource);
```

Is the initialization proper? Do I have to initialize the reader evertime a new thread calls onEvent method?

Comment: Is there special configuration you are doing in the SAX parser?  Is there a reason you aren't unmarshalling the `InputStream` directly?

Comment: We initially thought of using `jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream)`. Then after reading the api docs we understood that jaxb will pick a parsing technique by its own. We thought we can reduce the overhead on jaxb by making it use sax parser. And besides we only read the xml.No writes. So we started using jaxb with sax. The only configuration we do is we set a dummy EntityResolver on the XMLReader. Other than that we don't do any other configurations other than the code shown in this post. Should we stop doing the sax stuff and unmarshal the input stream directly? Is it the recommended way?

Comment: I would recommend using `unmarshal(InputStream)` directly.  JAXB implementations have their own optimizations to handle this type of optimization.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Okay, I will remove the sax stuff from the code and will keep it plain and simple. But I need some information to convince others to change the code? Can you please explain what kind of configurations make one to use SAX parser? Also can you please give me some useful links regarding jaxb and sax, good practices etc. I searched a lot and was not able to find any useful links

Comment: I tried using simple `unmarshallar.unmarshal(InputStream)` but it failed trying to validate the input stream against a dtd. We dont want to validate it against the dtd. So I set setShema(null) as mentioned in the api docs. Still it did not work. How can I use unmarshal without having validation?